# How can I programmatically provide a virtual directory?

Tags: filesystems, volume, mount, mounted-volumes

I'm not sure if "virtual directory" is the correct terminology, so an example might better at explaining what I mean:

If I have e.g. following array (could be written in any programming language):

```js
files = [
  { name: "file1.txt", content: "Content 1" },
  { name: "file2.txt", content: "Content 2" },
  { name: "file3.txt", content: "Content 3" },
]
```

I now want a function like:

```js
mountFilesAt("/usr/local/share/my-files", files)
```

So that it appears (read-only) in my filesystem like this:

[image: Screenshot of filesystem]

How can it be done?

Comment: What operating system? Maybe it's supported by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace

Comment: Cross platform ideally. I also stumbled upon FUSE, but it's kind of messy on macOS. My best idea so far is WebDAV (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), it's not ideal as you have to initiate the mount from the OS, but at least it can provide the filesystem view.